# Escaping quotes in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, escaping, quote

I'm trying to escape the quotes (and apostrofes and escape char) in a text string in javascript:

```
var text = 'Escape " and \' and /.';
var rx = new RegExp('/([\'"])/g');
console.log(text, ' ==> ', text.replace(rx,'//\1'));​​​​​
```

What I expect to be output is `Escape /" and /' and //.`, but instead I get `Escape " and ' and /.`.

I just can't seem to get this working and don't know what's wrong.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvtgf/

Comment: Why do you expect `/`? The escape character is `\\`..

Comment: Also, please stop using new RegExp('/([\'"])/g'); 
Javascript regular expressions are literals, that's like doing new String every time you want to define a string

Comment: @Rob W, because for the format I'm saving, I need `/` and I explicitely set `/` in the replacement string.

Comment: @Benjamin Grauenbaum: If I use `text.replace(/([\'"])/g, '//\1')` it doesn't replaces matched characters with empty string.

Comment: console.log("Escape ' and \" and /.".replace(/['"/]/g,function(str){return '/'+str})) Works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escaping means using backslash `\` but not slash `/`.

However, for your purposes you can try the following:

```
text.replace(/([/'"])/g, "/$1");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hvtgf/1/

Comment: Perfect! I guess the JS website I had as reference had the backreference syntax wrong.

Comment: @Martijn Hope it was not W3Schools :)